# How to produce, edit, and view HDR photographs format on XDR displays properly?

Tags: display, photos, adobe-photoshop, hdr

I am trying to increase the brightness of some SDR photographs so that they can fully utilise the brightness of "XDR" displays on apple devices to display a bright image (For example, screens on some apple devices can reach 1600 nits peak brightness for showing HDR contents).

In gimp, after importing an image, I set the "Image -> Precision" to "32 bit floating point", and "linear light". Then I increase the brightness. While it does look brighter, I am not sure how can I make sure I get the 1600 nits (or at least, say, 1000 nits). When I export the picture to `.hdr` format, and look at them in the Preview app, the colours looks completely different from what I see when I am editing in Gimp.

**What should I do to (1) use the full brightness of the displays and (2) get consistent result when I am editing and after I export?**

If it is not possible with gimp, please feel free to tell me what other software should I use (for example photoshop?).

I think this should not be difficult, because there are plenty of tutorials online about how to do this for **videos**. But when I try to search for how to edit **photos**, I do not get an answer. **It would be helpful if there is a link to a tutorial on making HDR photos.**

**Note:** by "HDR photographs", I mean image formats that could be viewed with more than, for example, 1000 nits of brightness, and extremely high contrast, on supported monitors, **just like HDR videos**. I am **NOT** discussing the technique of taking multiple photos of the same scene and combine them into one.